# How to display data from a JSON object with sigma.js

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

I would like to read node/edges information for a graph (sigma.js)
from a JSON variable. While it's quite easy to use an external JSON file
as input via a JSON parser, I could not find a way to use a JSON object 
directly defined in the JavaScript code. 
There seems to exist a method called 'read', but I could not get 
it to work (Source: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Graph-API).
Could someone give me a hint?

This is what I would like to have:

```
data = {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
  ]
}

sigma.parsers.json( data , {
  container: 'container',
  settings: {
    defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
  }
});
```

Thank you, cheers, Michael

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add your data as follows:

```
s = new sigma({ 
        graph: data,
        container: 'container',
        settings: {
            defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
        }
});
```

See also: [json-is-not-read-by-sigma-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795125/json-is-not-read-by-sigma-js)